# How to set transform origin in SVG

Tags: svg, coordinate-transformation

I need to resize and rotate certain elements in SVG document using javascript. The problem is, by default, it always applies the transform around the origin at `(0, 0)` – top left.

How can I re-define this transform anchor point?

I tried using the `transform-origin` attribute, but it does not affect anything.

This is how I did it:

```
svg.getDocumentById('someId').setAttribute('transform-origin', '75 240');
```

It does not seem to set the pivotal point to the point I specified although I can see in Firefox that the attribute is correctly set. I tried things like `center bottom` and `50% 100%` with and without parenthesis. Nothing worked so far.

Can anyone help?

Comment: FWIW, supposedly fixed as of Firefox 19 beta 3, though I'm still having problems in Firefox 22. Mozilla bugzilla listing: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=828286

Comment: @CTheDark, could you reconsider the accepted answer for this please? We now have a more modern solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720107/4375751

Answer (score 174, accepted):

To rotate use `transform="rotate(deg, cx, cy)"`, where deg is the degree you want to rotate and (cx, cy) define the centre of rotation.

For scaling/resizing, you have to translate by (-cx, -cy), then scale and then translate back to (cx, cy). You can do this with a [matrix transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform):

```
transform="matrix(sx, 0, 0, sy, cx-sx*cx, cy-sy*cy)"
```

Where sx is the scaling factor in the x-axis, sy in the y-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much. Rotate works perfectly I think, but scaling/resizing always end up having off by some random amount. I tried using the matrix and doing them separately like "translate(cx*sx, cy*sy) scale(sx, sy)". The same result.

Comment: Wouldn't it be transform="matrix(sx, 0, 0, sy, cx-sx*cx, cy-sy*cy)"? Because you want to only translate by the difference. I think this logic is correct, but it still gives me off positions...

Comment: Now it works! I was just using wrong cx and cy values! THanks a lot!

Comment: @Charlemagne Are you saying that the original formula or your formula worked for you?  Because only Charlemagne's formula worked for me.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge will this same matrix transform work for regular (non-SVG) css?  I've been trying to do the math myself, but am having probelms.

Comment: @JayStevens Yes, the matrix transform will work for any system, it's just maths. The only difference might be the notation. As far as I can tell, the CSS matrix transform uses the same notation as for SVGs, so the same six numbers in that order should work.

Comment: Just to clarify, cx and cy need to be offsets of the _center_ of the box your scaling in. This tripped me up for a bit, as I was thinking in CSS box models. @forresto alludes to this in his answer below.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge Thanks for the info. I want to resize an svg element according to mousemove. How should i calculate sx,sy?

Comment: @PeterCollingridge does it mean that when I also apply `translate` the matrix would look like this `transform="matrix(sx, 0, 0, sy, tx+cx-sx*cx, ty+cy-sy*cy)"`?

Comment: @thednp Correct, assuming the translation happens after the other transformations (which is most likely the case).

Comment: the portion of your solution that help me was: transform="rotate(deg, cx, cy)". I was using it to rotate svg text on a vertical line in Nuxt. Concrete code example below:

 <text
        fill="#FFF"
        :x="this.halfScreenWidth"
        text-anchor="left"
        :transform="`rotate(90, ${this.halfScreenWidth}, 0)`"
      >

Answer (score 137):

## New 2020 solution

```
svg * { 
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

applying `transform-box: fill-box` will make an element within an SVG behave as a normal HTML element. Then you can apply `transform-origin: center` (or something else) as you would normally

that's right, `transform-box: fill-box`. These days, there's no need for any complicated matrix stuff

Comment: VERY useful solution, this sould be upvoted higher. this is exactly what I needed; thank you! svg and html elements have subtle differences when transforming and transitioning. i was perplexed with an animation bug for hours until i found this answer... with `transform-box: fill-box;` you can make svg elementes respect `transform-origin` in a sane manner / like you'd expect!

Comment: no worries dude! I had similar relief when I found it (thank you @Robert Longson)!! 
It fixed the massive headache I was facing trying to control dots on an svg map :sweat: :sweat: :sweat:

Comment: Please note: transform-box was introduced fully in 2017 - 6 years after this question was asked & first answered. Thus you might have to forgive people for 'missing the trick'.

Comment: Hey SimplSam, I have updated the answer to be more friendly towards the past

Comment: this definitely the right answer, just add it to whatever SVG element that is being animated. you don't even need transform-origin since its the default behavior

Comment: Maybe clarify that you need to replace `svg` with a specific element or needing to use something like `svg *`. Maybe use `[your svg element]` instead of `svg`. Or maybe simply remove the selector from your example?

Comment: After 2 hours of researching options I luckily stumbled upon your magical solution which will save me _days_ of work on a project. Thanks!

Comment: I have been looking for a tool like this for a long time, thanks mate!

Answer (score 22):

If you can use a fixed value (not "center" or "50%"), you can use CSS instead:

```
-moz-transform-origin: 25px 25px;
-ms-transform-origin:  25px 25px;
-o-transform-origin: 25px 25px;
-webkit-transform-origin:  25px 25px;
transform-origin: 25px 25px;
```

Some browsers (like Firefox) won't handle relative values correctly.

Comment: Wow.  Would +10 if I could.  This saved my day!  Thanks.

Comment: How to do this and just this in JavaScript?

Comment: Like `element.setAttribute('transform-origin', '25px 25px')` ?

Answer (score 17):

For scaling without having to use the `matrix` transformation:

```
transform="translate(cx, cy) scale(sx sy) translate(-cx, -cy)"
```

And here it is in CSS:

```
transform: translate(cxpx, cypx) scale(sx, sy) translate(-cxpx, -cypx)
```

Comment: simple and effective, +1

Answer (score 14):

If you're like me and want to pan and then zoom with transform-origin, you'll need a little more.

```
// <g id="view"></g>
var view = document.getElementById("view");

var state = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1
};

// Origin of transform, set to mouse position or pinch center
var oX = window.innerWidth/2;
var oY = window.innerHeight/2;

var changeScale = function (scale) {
  // Limit the scale here if you want
  // Zoom and pan transform-origin equivalent
  var scaleD = scale / state.scale;
  var currentX = state.x;
  var currentY = state.y;
  // The magic
  var x = scaleD * (currentX - oX) + oX;
  var y = scaleD * (currentY - oY) + oY;

  state.scale = scale;
  state.x = x;
  state.y = y;

  var transform = "matrix("+scale+",0,0,"+scale+","+x+","+y+")";
  //var transform = "translate("+x+","+y+") scale("+scale+")"; //same
  view.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", transform);
};
```

Here it is working: http://forresto.github.io/dataflow-prototyping/react/

Comment: Your github link 404s

Comment: Hello @NuclearPeon, this is awesome, but I can't seem to implement it in my code. The SVG element i'd like it to apply to is already a variable called "mainGrid". I tried replacing the instance of "view" with "mainGrid" with no effect. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @sakeferret the most obvious things to check for is that the `id` matches in the `getElementById` and the documents' `id="..."` attribute. It's hard to know for sure without seeing the code. If you don't want to post it as an SO question, you can try creating the simplest example using your attribute names until it works/you find the issue, then add the rest back in.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the attribute  (`transform-origin="center"`) of the embedded element just inside the DOM did the trick for me

```
          <circle
          fill="#FFFFFF"
          cx="82"
          cy="81.625"
          r="81.5"
          transform-origin="center"
        ></circle>
```

Works well with using css transforms

Comment: this doesn't work all the time. in some cases you'll need to add `transform-box: fill-box`. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720107/4375751

Comment: I am talking of using the attribute inside the DOM ((`transform-origin="center"`), not (`transform-origin: center`)). Tested it in all modern browsers and it worked without using fill-box

Answer (score 1):

You can build whatever you want around 0,0 origin, then put it into a group `<g></g>` and matrix-translate the whole group.
Like that, the object will always rotate around 0,0 , but the whole group is moved (translated) elsewhere and translation matrix is applied after the rotation.

```html
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 160 200)">
  <polygon id="arrow-A" class="arrow" points="0,4 -90,0 0,-4 "/>
</g>


<style>

.arrow {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

/* OR */

#arrow-A {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

</style>

OR scripting: 

<script> 
  document.getElementById("arrow-A").setAttribute("transform", "rotate(60)");
</script>
```

This will create an arrow (eg. for a gauge), the broader end at [0,0] and move it to [160, 200]. Whichever rotation is applied to class "arrow", will rotate it around [160, 200].

Tested in: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, MS Edge

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But I was using **D3** to position my elements, and wanted the **transform** and **transition** to be handled by CSS. This was my original code, which I got working in Chrome 65:

```
//...
this.layerGroups.selectAll('.dot')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('transform-origin', (d,i)=> `${valueScale(d.value) * Math.sin( sliceSize * i)} 
                                     ${valueScale(d.value) * Math.cos( sliceSize * i + Math.PI)}`)
//... etc (set the cx, cy and r below) ...
```

This allowed me to set the `cx`,`cy`, and `transform-origin` values in javascript using the same data.

**BUT this didn't work in Firefox!** What I had to do was wrap the `circle` in the `g` tag and `translate` it using the same positioning formula from above. I then appended the `circle` in the `g` tag, and set its `cx` and `cy` values to `0`. From there, `transform: scale(2)` would scale from the center as expected. The final code looked like this.

```
this.layerGroups.selectAll('.dot')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attrs({
    class: d => `dot ${d.metric}`,
    transform: (d,i) => `translate(${valueScale(d.value) * Math.sin( sliceSize * i)} ${valueScale(d.value) * Math.cos( sliceSize * i + Math.PI)})`
  })
  .append('circle')
  .attrs({
    r: this.opts.dotRadius,
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
  })
```

After making this change, I changed my CSS to target the `circle` instead of the `.dot`, to add the `transform: scale(2)`. I didn't even need use `transform-origin`.

**NOTES:**

1. I am using `d3-selection-multi` in the second example. This allows me to pass an object to `.attrs` instead of repeating `.attr` for every attribute.
2. When using a string template literal, be aware of line-breaks as illustrated in the first example. This will include a newline in the output and may break your code.

Comment: Perhaps if you set transform-box: fill-box; Firefox would have worked the way you wanted it to.

Comment: tried that. didn't seem to work. It **did** work after i changed the `svg:transform-origin.enabled` pref in the firefox's `about:config` page. But... that didn't seem like an adequate solution. I also found a discrepancy between `transform-origin: 50% 50%` and `transform-origin: center center`.

Comment: the svg.transform-origin.enabled pref was removed many versions ago. Unless you're using a very old version there should be no difference between 50% and center. Feel free to raise a bugzilla bug if there is a difference in Firefox 59 or later.