# CSS transform-origin from center on SVG ignored in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, css-transforms

I have an svg icon inlined in my html that when hovered, applies a css scale transform. I've set the transform-origin property to center/50% on the path's parent group* and it works great in Webkit but ignored in Firefox. Any ideas?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRZwZ/)

HTML/SVG:

```
<div class="col3 build websites-content">
    <svg class="svg-icon icon-build" width="75px" height="75px">
        <g><path fill="#fff" d="M17.5,39.7L28.8,42v13.5l9.5-8.5L49,55.5l4.5-36L17.5,39.7z M35.5,42L31,48.7V42l18-18L35.5,42z"/></g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS (ignoring vendor prefixes):

```
.websites-content g {
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transform-origin: center center;
}

.websites-content:hover g {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

*I have other icons containing several paths, necessitating a group – just using this single path example for clarity

Comment: I'm playing around with your Fiddle in FireFox and what's weird is that it doesn't like `center` or `50%` for the `transform-origin` value yet it's fine with a pixel value...

Comment: These might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938331/transform-origin-for-css-animation-on-svg-working-in-chrome-not-ff/18943090#18943090

Comment: Yeah it is weird re. the pixel value. And thanks for those links, but they are hacky with extra markup. Thank you very much for looking!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work on both using `translate` to compensate the translation caused by scaling:

```
.websites-content:hover g {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
 -moz-transform:    scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
 -ms-transform:     scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
  transform:        scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/RRZwZ/2/)

Comment: Thanks man, you are correct and it works but I need something more generic as I have several icons I need to apply this too

Comment: Using the pixel value in `transform-origin` as suggested is probably a better solution in this case.