# SVG image element rotation

Tags: css, animation, svg

I need to create a bean shape with rotating background.
I have SVG with an image element. The image has class "rotation". I use CSS to rotate it.

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/olam/pen/hJCla

It works only in Chrome. 
In Firefox seems that transform-origin:50% 50% doesn't work.
In Safari I can't see image at all.

Would be awesome if you can give me some advice.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firefox, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891074.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch to using SVG animation.  It should then work on all browsers.

Alter your image element so that it looks like the following.

```
<image class="rotation" overflow="visible" width="506" height="267"
       xlink:href="---snipped out for brevity---"
       transform="matrix(0.6998 0 0 0.6998 -42.1211 -26.0269)">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate" 
                      from="0 253 133" 
                      to="-360 253 133" 
                      dur="25s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</image>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/45kYP/1/)

**Update**

If you use absolute coords rather than percentages, the original codepen example will work in Firefox.

```
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: spin;
animation-timing-function: linear;
transform-origin:253px 133px;
```

Comment: All browsers except for IE.

Comment: Ah yes.  Forgot that.  Thanks Erik.

Comment: This time I don't care about IE:)
Thanks a lot for help!