# Rotate a SVG hamburger icon into an X?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, css-transforms

I've designed a **3-bar icon using pure SVG** code in HTML. I'm using CSS3 transforms to rotate the top & bottom bars into an X shape. The problem is that they rotate around their own center, but I need them rotating around the icon's center. To get around this I've adjusted their X/Y coordinates.

This causes a LOT of buggy issues with Internet Explorer, Firefox, & Safari. Chrome seems to be alright but obviously I'd like to code this the "right" way so it'll work in all browsers.

[Here's my live CodePen](http://codepen.io/yahtzee_party/pen/ZGXXao)

HTML

```
<svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="80">
  <g class="icon">
    <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
    <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
    <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.hamburger { display:block; text-align:center; }
svg { cursor:pointer; }

.frstbar, .scndbar, .thrdbar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s linear;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
}
#burgericon.open .frstbar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .thrdbar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .scndbar { width: 0; opacity: 0; }
```

JS

```
$('#burgericon').on('click', function(e) {

  if($(this).attr('class') != "open") {
      $(this).attr('class','open');
      $('.frstbar').attr('x','25').attr('y','-5');
      $('.thrdbar').attr('x','-35').attr('y','55');
    } 
  else {
    $(this).attr('class','default');
    $('.frstbar').attr('x','10').attr('y','10');
      $('.thrdbar').attr('x','10').attr('y','60');
    }
});
```

I also think changing the X/Y coords is causing a blurry effect. I've added a screenshot below. First you'll see the completed X icon and then you'll see how it looks when animated back to default.

The bars aren't perfectly straight but instead they look crooked for some reason.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93SRK.jpg)

I'm still new to SVG manipulation so I'm not sure how to properly rotate `<rect>` elements with CSS3/JS. Any help or tips in the right direction would be more than appreciated.

Comment: codepen probably isn't the best demo site for errors due to its auto-save feature. Would it be possible to post your markup here as well (for future readers?)

Comment: It's strange ... even in Chrome, if I try it several times, some will fail ...

Comment: I don't think the **linear** `transition-timing-function` gives the transition time to finish properly. Switching to the default **ease** seems to fix it in my limited testing.

Comment: @jbutler483 Sure! Just added all the code so it's visible from this post without CodePen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the JS positioning by using the CSS [`transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). You can set it on the left of the first and second bars with `transform-origin: 0 50%;`.

This way they will cross each other when they are rotated :

```js
document.getElementById('burgericon').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.frstbar,.scndbar,.thrdbar {
  transition: all 0.35s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
#burgericon.open .frstbar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .thrdbar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#burgericon.open .scndbar {
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hamburger">
  <svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="80">
    <g class="icon">
      <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
      <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="70" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" fill="#414141" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</nav>
<div>
</div>
```

Credits to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941833/how-to-properly-rotate-a-3-bar-svg-hamburger-icon-into-an-x/30942603?noredirect=1#comment49920767_30942603) for the JS

*Note that the `transform-origin` property needs the same vendor prefixes as the `transform` property. I have omited them for both in the above snippet*

Comment: Nice and simple jquery solution :P

Comment: It's also just as simple (if not more so) with plain JavaScript: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gog3e1ae/).

Comment: This does seem cleaner but do you know why it won't work in IE? I'm testing on the latest IE11 both codes from web-tiki and @DavidThomas but IE seems troublesome. I know that's a pesky one and I'd be okay to forego support in IE, but it also seems buggy in FireFox too. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xjkejbo/)

Comment: @DavidThomas definetly simpler in plain JS

Comment: @ThomasLancy FF doesn't support the transform-origin property for svg elements. There is a workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: @web-tiki It does support transform-origin on svg elements as long as you avoid percentages.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks it does seem to work in FF using pixels. Doesn't seem to fit perfectly but it looks much better. I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xjkejbo/1/) with FF support - probably the best I can do with current browser standards.

Comment: Percentage support is coming. It's implemented but hidden behind a disabled pref, we're unhiding/enabling it soon. Not sure yet which version will get it first though.

Answer (score 5):

## CSS

Using css `transform: rotate()` I rotated the elements so they form the X
Using css `opacity` and transitions; made the object gradually go transparent.

```css
.icon {
  stroke: none;
  fill: #777;
}
.icon .frstbar {
  transform-origin: 10% 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.icon:hover .frstbar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.icon .thrdbar {
  transform-origin: 10% 50%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.icon:hover .thrdbar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.scndbar {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.icon:hover .scndbar {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="burgericon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g class="icon">
    <rect class="frstbar" x="10" y="10" width="90" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" />
    <rect class="scndbar" x="10" y="35" width="90" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" />
    <rect class="thrdbar" x="10" y="60" width="90" height="12" rx="7" ry="7" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see why you removed JS to simplify. But I notice this solution also gets wonky in Firefox - any idea why? Even just modern up-to-date browser support seems to be impossible. Here's a [Firefox screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/E6TycUs.jpg) from your demo along with a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f88jvro5/)

Comment: Hey Persijn i guesss you should add hover styles to svg instead of the group, as when you hover between the strokes, the hover wont fire!

Comment: @TimKrul naaaaa i kinda like it this way :D