# Animation for hamburger icon animation not working

Tags: html, css, animation, hamburger-menu

I am trying to create a spin animation for my hamburger icon and it refuses to work for whatever reason. I have even tried putting it as ".hamburger a:hover" and nothing seems to work. Can anyone find the solution please?

CSS

[image]

HTML

[image]

Comment: PLease create a code snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30942603/7358765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS `display: inline-block` or `display: block` so the element will have a width and height.

```css
.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.75 ease-in-out !important;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <a class="hamburger" href="#" onclick="dropdown()"> &equiv; </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `.hamburger :hover` to `.hamburger:hover` - no space.
2. `.hamburger a` means an element with a hamburger class that contains inside it an `a` tag. You dont have that in your code. Change `.hamburger a` to `a.hamburger` - That measns an `a` tag with the hamburger class.

Comment: Hello, I've done both ways, nothing changed. Also when changing the padding in the a.hamburger class, it also does not have any affect whatsoever.