# SVG Animation rotates in wrong place

Tags: css, svg

I'm quite new to SVG animations and I am struggleing a bit with it.

I have written the below code to rotate an image around a center point.  However, it is cutting off the top and left of the immage.

```html
 <svg width="350" height="350">
      <g transform="translate(175, 175)">
        <svg>
        <g>
          <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" begin="0" dur="500ms" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>
    
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="140" stroke="#70AD47" stroke-width="5" fill="#E2F0D6"></circle>
    
          <text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dy="10" class="bubbleTitle" fill="#70AD47">Top</text>
    
          <circle cx="0" cy="-120" r="50" stroke="#70AD47" stroke-width="3" fill="#E2F0D6"></circle>
    
          <text x="0" y="-120" text-anchor="middle" dy="0">
            <tspan font-size="14" class="bubbleText" x="0" dy="-1.5em">Sent</tspan>
            <tspan font-size="40" class="bubbleText" x="0" dy="1.0em">#</tspan>
          </text>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Any help with this would be hugely apreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Svg transform is kind of challenging. Usually it is easier to put your svg in to a div and transform div. You may [read that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox) to get bigger picture is why it is an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewBox` attribute is missing. If you set it properly the inner translation is no longer necessary.

Also remove the nested `SVG` element

```html
<svg width="350" height="350" viewBox="-140 -175 280 350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" begin="0" dur="500ms" repeatCount="1"></animateTransform>

      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="140" stroke="#70AD47" stroke-width="5" fill="#E2F0D6"></circle>
      <text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" dy="10" class="bubbleTitle" fill="#70AD47">Top</text>
      <circle cx="0" cy="-120" r="50" stroke="#70AD47" stroke-width="3" fill="#E2F0D6"></circle>

      <text x="0" y="-120" text-anchor="middle" dy="0">
        <tspan font-size="14" class="bubbleText" x="0" dy="-1.5em">Sent</tspan>
        <tspan font-size="40" class="bubbleText" x="0" dy="1.0em">#</tspan>
      </text>
</svg>
```