# Percentage transform-origin for SVG not obeyed in Firefox, only sometimes in WebKit

Tags: css, html, svg, transform, css-transforms

I have this ice cream cone SVG graphic, and I want to transform the scoop with a `transform-origin` of `50% 100%` (center bottom). Firefox claims to obey (i.e. the inspector notes the correct `transform-origin`) but in fact transforms about the upper left corner. WebKit, bizarrely, will only obey if a parent element has `font-size:100%` set.

These are very similar questions but only pertain to Firefox:

1. [Setting transform-origin on SVG group not working in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox)
2. [How to set transform origin in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711610/how-to-set-transform-origin-in-svg?rq=1)
3. [Transform Origin not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369560/transform-origin-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: The bug that you've mentioned as a comment in the other questions doesn't have anything to do with transform-origin. If I were you I'd raise a new bug in bugzilla with your testcase attached.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after the fact, my bad... and I'll do that.

Comment: @Toph I found your bug report in bugzilla. You might want to vote to get [bug #923193](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193) solved. As of writing, it only has 4 votes.

Comment: Supposedly fixed in Firefox 41 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193 but in Nightly it still doesn't behave as expected (i.e. like WebKit / Blink).

Answer (score 1):

Just recently I came across the same problem; here's how I went about solving it:

According to [this page on SVG animation with CSS transforms](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/), major browsers simply aren't consistent in applying `transform-origin` to SVG elements yet. The author of the page created a JavaScript animation platform called [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), and explains some of its `transform-origin` calculations in the article. While you're more than welcome to implement the math yourself with JavaScript to fix SVG origins, I took a look at GSAP (specifically the TweenLite tool) and it ended up suiting my needs perfectly. If you're OK using an external library in your website, I would recommend using his tool to perform animation on SVG elements, since it allows you to animate elements consistently across all major browsers. It's obviously not preferable to `transform-origin` simply working like it's supposed to, but until browsers update, this has been a suitable alternative for me.