# CSS 3D transform in Firefox is skewed around the top left

Tags: css, firefox, 3d

I have a simple 3D transform, which Chrome renders correctly, but in Firefox seems to be getting skewed around the top left corner of the transformed element.

Below is the view when hovering over the transform property in the Firefox debugger. The red shape is the element I'm trying to transform, and the blue shape showing Firefox's projection of it is actually correct, but for some reason the red shape isn't matching this.

[image: Firefox debug view (screenshot)]

Here is the minimal code: [(codepen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emwGzR):

```
<div style="width: 1065px; height: 1095px; perspective: 597.491px;">
    <div style="transform-style: preserve-3d; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; width: 1065px; height: 1095px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 597.491px) matrix3d(-0.975388, -0.0931864, 0.199836, 0, 0, -0.906306, -0.422623, 0, -0.220496, 0.412221, -0.884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) translate3d(532.5px, 547.5px, 0px);">
        <div style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px) matrix3d(-0.001862, 0, -0.00117, 0, -0.000247, -0.00215, 0.000394, 0, 0.001143, -0.000465, -0.00182, 0, -0.519918, 0.211585, 0.827596, 1);width:760px;height:350px;background:red">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The codepen also shows in Firefox that the scroll position is changing the red shape, which it doesn't in Chrome:

Any ideas?

Comment: What would [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) do?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the differing ways that Firefox handles the `transform-origin` CSS property; see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522930/percentage-transform-origin-for-svg-not-obeyed-in-firefox-only-sometimes-in-web/30416810#30416810) for more explanation.

As per Philip's comment on your question, I would suggest taking a look at an animation platform like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), since not all browsers deal with `transform-origin` properly yet.