# Transform origin on SVGs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm new to animating SVGs & I've come across a problem that only seems to happen in Firefox. I've created a animation here - http://codepen.io/iamali/pen/txvpo - of a sky scene. The sun should rotate & fade in & out.

It works fine in Chrome, but for some reason it appears to ignore the transform-origin value in Firefox and the sun goes AWOL. Does anyone know of such an issue in Firefox? Or could it be anything else? I've tried Google all sorts of terms but there doesn't seem to be much out there on it.

Thanks!

Comment: the link to the example seems to be broken

Answer (score 8, accepted):

transform-origin with percentage units works from [Firefox 43 onwards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175492).

Comment: `transform-origin` was supported to some degree in Firefox 40 for SVG elements, that is, it has an effect on them. It's behavior just isn't always correct.

Comment: Well it works fine if you don't use percentages if that's what you mean.