# Inline SVG's coordinate system thrown off in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, gecko

Right now the problem is live at http://ti.gt/ if you want to see what I'm working with.

I have a menu button rendered with SVG, and it renders how I would like in Chrome, Safari, IE9+, and their mobile versions:

[image]

In Firefox (both desktop & mobile), instead this happens:

[image]

It's coded like so:

```
<a href="/menu" class="menu-link" id="menuLink" aria-label="Navigation">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 160 160">
        <polygon points="160,168 0,168 60,60 160,0"/>
        <polygon class="bar bar1" points="60,90 150,85 147,60 65,65" fill="#fff"/>
        <polygon class="bar bar2" points="45,125 147,120 150,100 57,100" fill="#fff"/>
        <polygon class="bar bar3" points="45,152 150,150 155,132 50,135" fill="#fff"/>
    </svg>
</a>
```

The CSS used for styling it:

```
.menu-link {
    background: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

(It intentionally extends past the browser edges to help with some juddering on mobile with `position: fixed`.)

The primary `<path>` providing the backdrop appears to be identical, but the `<path>`s providing the bars have gone drunk. I've futzed around with attribute sizing, CSS sizing, `viewBox`, `preserveAspectRatio`, and other obvious methods, but any change in Firefox heralds breakage everywhere else.

What's going on with Firefox and its positioning? Can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transform origin on SVGs in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203492/transform-origin-on-svgs-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `transform-origin` property on class `bar`.  Firefox's implementation of `transform-origin` is buggy when applied to SVG elements.

See: [Transform origin on SVGs in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203492/transform-origin-on-svgs-in-firefox)

Comment: By Joe, so it is. Thanks for submitting it to bugzilla, by the way!

Comment: That wasn't me who submitted it :)

Comment: Oh, huh. [Thought I recognized the avatar.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193#c50)