# SVG animated spinner not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

I've been trying to implement this spinner, built by Fran Pérez:

http://codepen.io/mrrocks/pen/EiplA

It works great in Safari and Chrome, but doesn't work at all in Firefox or IE.

Has anyone got any suggestions on a fix?

## HTML

```
<svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
</svg>
```

## SCSS

```
// This is just to center the spinner

html, body { height: 100%; }

body {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

// Here is where the magic happens

$offset: 187;
$duration: 1.4s;

.spinner {
  animation: rotator $duration linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotator {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(270deg); }
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: $offset;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    dash $duration ease-in-out infinite, 
    colors ($duration*4) ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes colors {
    0% { stroke: #4285F4; }
    25% { stroke: #DE3E35; }
    50% { stroke: #F7C223; }
    75% { stroke: #1B9A59; }
  100% { stroke: #4285F4; }
}

@keyframes dash {
 0% { stroke-dashoffset: $offset; }
 50% {
   stroke-dashoffset: $offset/4;
   transform:rotate(135deg);
 }
 100% {
   stroke-dashoffset: $offset;
   transform:rotate(450deg);
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't use transform-origin: center; with Firefox currently. You'll need to work out the centre and use the actual value i.e. not a percentage and not center.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203492/transform-origin-on-svgs-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, I've changed the value to be 'transform-origin: 30px 30px 0;' and it now works in Firefox.  Still no luck in IE9 or IE10. (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aiptI)

Comment: With FF 37 the edges are cut :(