# Circular animation not working on SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following animation applied to my simple SVG:

```
@keyframes rotate  {
    100%  {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}

.keepRotatingOne  {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -o-animation-name: rotate;
    animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -o-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Basically i need the outer most ring of my SVG to rotate in a circular motion , by staying in its current place ,whats happening right now is that, the outer ring is not staying in its current place, but rater rotating away. **[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0jxmwgcq/)**

If i apply the above animation to a to a `div` element however, it works perfectly fine, **[SEE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0jxmwgcq/1/)**.

So why is the animation not working on the SVG ? It would be nice if somebody could explain why its not working and also give me a solution to circumvent this problem.

Comment: here's some good reading on [transforms with SVG](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)

Comment: @Quoid haha Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the bug with `transform-origin` in some versions of Firefox, by reconfiguring your SVG a little.  See below.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,400italic,600,700,800);
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #31A6DE;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #31A6DE;
}

.st2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.st3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.keepRotatingOne {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 960 560;" xml:space="preserve">

    <g transform="translate(549.9, 168)">
      <g class="keepRotatingOne">
        <polygon id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" points="537,301.5 564,301.5 569,275.8 594.7,267.5 613.3,287.1 635.7,271.7 625,247 637,233.7 
 662.7,242.3 674.3,218 653.3,200.3 657.6,184 683.5,179.3 683.5,152 656.1,147.3 652.2,131 672.6,113.3 659.3,90.7 633.3,98.3 
 619,84.3 630,64.3 607,49.7 590,68.3 568.3,62.3 563.7,34.5 537,34.5 531,62.3 506.3,69.5 488.3,49.6 465,64.7 476,89.7 465,102.3 
 438,93.7 426.3,117.7 447,135 443,152 416.3,157 417,184.3 443.7,188.8 448.5,205.8 428.2,222.7 441.7,246.3 467.5,237.8 480,250.7 
 470,274.3 492.3,287.8 510.5,269 532.5,275.5 " transform="translate(-549.9, -168)"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <ellipse id="XMLID_3_" class="st0" cx="550.5" cy="168.5" rx="91.6" ry="89.5" />
    <text id="XMLID_4_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 519.3203 166.4999)">
      <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st1 st2 st3">ProCess</tspan>
      <tspan x="-36.4" y="16.8" class="st1 st2 st3">Standardization</tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
```

**How it works**

We transform the polygon so that its centre sits on the origin (0,0).  Then we wrap the polygon in a group element and apply the rotation element to that.  That gives us a cog that is rotating around (0,0).  Finally, we wrap that group in another group that transforms the cog back to it's original position.

```
<g transform="translate(<back to original position>)">
  <g class="applyRotationAnimationToThisElement">
    <polygon transform="translate(<to the origin>)" ... />
  </g>
</g>
```

We need two extra groups here because the object we are rotating can't have it's own transform. That's because it will get replaced by the one in the CSS, and destroy the effect.

Comment: Great explanation Paul.

Answer (score 1):

It must to spin around its own axis that is placed on 50% top 50% left of itself.
Add this to .keepRotatingOne:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvt4t57u/)

> 2D transformations can change the x- and y-axis of an element. [***- w3s***](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: could you explain how you came up with that solution? also note, it doesn't work in firefox 45.0

Comment: it must to spin around its own axis that is placed on 50% top 50% left of itself;

Comment: The problem in Firefox is caused by this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061 and CSS animations on SVG elements don't work on IE, I would recommend an animation library such as GSAP http://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: That's currently a specification issue and not really a Firefox bug.

Comment: [**check this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530797/svg-rotation-animation-failing-in-ie-and-ff) and then [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938331/transform-origin-for-css-animation-on-svg-working-in-chrome-not-ff) and also [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139090/setting-transform-origin-on-svg-group-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a couple of years late.I think they fixed that over the course of years

I fixed it with this code

```
.keepRotatingOne {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```