# transform-origin not working in Firefox even properties in percentage value

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-transforms

CSS3 `transform-origin` not working in firefox browser.

I am trying to run `transform: rotate(360deg);` in `@keyframes` for `<g class="tyre">` as child of `<svg class='truck'>`. In the result the truck wheel rotation works fine for all other browser except **chrome**

[image]

There are similar questions in Stack Overflow unfortunately none of them are related with the question.

```css
.tyre{
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  to  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  to  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg class='truck' viewBox='0 0 93 53' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height="180">
  <g class='chase' fill-rule='evenodd' fill='none'>
    <path d='M32.087 35.263h3.023V5.973h-3.023v29.29z' fill='#EE7C00'></path>
    <path d='M87.84 35.262H5.007v4.065L9.07 43.39h74.707l4.062-4.063v-4.065z' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M35.11 35.262h57.445v-3.966H35.11v3.966z' fill='#F09E00'></path>
    <path d='M90.393 35.262h2.16v-3.966h-2.16v3.966z' fill='#E2000F'></path>
    <path d='M17.498.493L2.91 15.08v20.182h29.175V.492H17.498z' fill='#FCC400'></path>
    <path d='M29.495 2.905H18.16L6.823 14.24h22.67V2.905z' fill='#575656'></path>
    <path d='M0 35.262h10.014v-3.966H0v3.966z' fill='#F09E00'></path>
    <path d='M5.008 37.294h82.83v-2.032H5.01v2.032z' fill='#575656'></path>
    <path d='M.75 29.858h2.16v-6.995H.75v6.995zM11.015 20.074h3.497v-2.16h-3.497v2.16z' fill='#E2000F'></path>
    <path d='M28.447 35.262h1.05V14.24h-1.05v21.022z' fill='#EE7C00'></path>
    <path d='M53.51 27.23h34.33v4.065H53.51V27.23z' fill='#575656'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyre'>
    <path d='M64.827 36.593a9.61 9.61 0 0 0 0 13.59c3.753 3.754 9.837 3.754 13.59 0a9.61 9.61 0 0 0-13.59-13.59' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M67.287 39.053a6.13 6.13 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.13 6.13 0 1 0 0-8.67' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M67.287 39.053a6.133 6.133 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.134 6.134 0 0 0 8.67 0l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M68.784 40.55a4.012 4.012 0 0 0 5.676 5.677 4.012 4.012 0 0 0-5.676-5.676' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M65.526 37.293A8.62 8.62 0 1 1 77.72 49.486a8.62 8.62 0 0 1-12.192-12.193m-.385-.386c-3.578 3.578-3.578 9.384 0 12.963 3.58 3.58 9.385 3.58 12.964 0 3.578-3.58 3.578-9.385 0-12.963-3.58-3.58-9.386-3.58-12.964 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyre'>
    <path d='M13.038 36.593c-3.754 3.754-3.754 9.838 0 13.59a9.61 9.61 0 0 0 13.59 0c3.754-3.752 3.754-9.836 0-13.59a9.61 9.61 0 0 0-13.59 0' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M15.498 39.054a6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.13 6.13 0 0 0 8.67 0 6.13 6.13 0 0 0-8.67-8.67' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M15.498 39.054a6.13 6.13 0 1 0 8.67 8.67l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M16.996 40.55a4.012 4.012 0 1 0 5.675 5.677 4.014 4.014 0 0 0-5.674-5.676' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M13.737 37.293a8.622 8.622 0 0 1 12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0 12.192 8.622 8.622 0 0 1-12.193 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0-12.192m-.385-.385a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0 12.962c3.578 3.58 9.384 3.58 12.962 0a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0-12.962 9.164 9.164 0 0 0-12.962 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyre'>
    <path d='M44.406 36.593c-3.753 3.754-3.753 9.838 0 13.59 3.754 3.755 9.838 3.755 13.59 0 3.755-3.752 3.755-9.836 0-13.59-3.752-3.753-9.836-3.753-13.59 0' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M46.868 39.054a6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.128 6.128 0 0 0 8.67 0 6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0-8.67 6.13 6.13 0 0 0-8.67 0' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M46.868 39.054a6.13 6.13 0 1 0 8.67 8.67l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M48.364 40.55a4.014 4.014 0 1 0 0 0' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M45.106 37.293a8.622 8.622 0 0 1 12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0 12.192 8.622 8.622 0 0 1-12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0-12.192m-.385-.385a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0 12.962c3.58 3.58 9.385 3.58 12.963 0 3.58-3.578 3.58-9.384 0-12.962a9.164 9.164 0 0 0-12.962 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're missing a complete description of what you want to achieve and what's the result. A code alone is not enough to understand what you want.

Comment: `transform-origin` is poorly implemented/supported below FF42. - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923193

Comment: @KittMedia The question has been updated as per your request. Please let me now if you more explanation

Comment: @Paulie_D My FF is **42.0** and FDeveloperEdition is **44.0a2 (2015-12-08)**. Still the result is same for both bowsers 

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203492/transform-origin-on-svgs-in-firefox

Comment: @Paulie_D I am sure that `transform-origin` can be fixed with some hack technics. here is one example http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/Cpuyq

Comment: Looks like you need transform-box: fill-box although that's only supported by FDeveloperEdition.

Comment: @halfer yes, he gave me the proper solution the two questions with detailed explanation. Here is the second question which similar to same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298861/svg-animatetransform-not-working-same-as-css3-transform

Comment: OK, thanks for accepting it.

Comment: @halfer Cheers mate 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise the comments you have been getting:

1. The `transform-origin` property with percentage values on SVG elements has been broken in Firefox, and has only just been fixed/implemented.
2. The meaning of `transform-origin: 50% 50%` when applied to SVG elements has not been fully specified until recently.  Chrome used the centre of the element's *bounding box*.  Firefox uses the centre of the SVG.
3. How percentage origins are to be calculated has only recently been decided.  There is a new property called `transform-box`.  See: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box

The default value of `transform-box` for SVG elements is `view-box` (typically the centre of the whole SVG).  However Chrome currently uses the equivalent of `fill-box`.

In summary, you should not rely on Chrome's behaviour.  It is probably going to change to match what is specified by the new `transform-box` property.

If you want to have your SVG work now on both browsers, don't use percentage values in `transform-origin`. Use absolute coordinates.  See example below.

```css
.tyreA {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 71.59px 43.42px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 71.59px 43.42px;
  transform-origin: 71.59px 43.42px;
  transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.tyreB {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 19.83px 43.39px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 19.83px 43.39px;
  transform-origin: 19.83px 43.39px;
  transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.tyreC {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 51.2px 43.39px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 51.2px 43.39px;
  transform-origin: 51.2px 43.39px;
  transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  to  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  to  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg class='truck' viewBox='0 0 93 53' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height="180">
  <g class='chase' fill-rule='evenodd' fill='none'>
    <path d='M32.087 35.263h3.023V5.973h-3.023v29.29z' fill='#EE7C00'></path>
    <path d='M87.84 35.262H5.007v4.065L9.07 43.39h74.707l4.062-4.063v-4.065z' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M35.11 35.262h57.445v-3.966H35.11v3.966z' fill='#F09E00'></path>
    <path d='M90.393 35.262h2.16v-3.966h-2.16v3.966z' fill='#E2000F'></path>
    <path d='M17.498.493L2.91 15.08v20.182h29.175V.492H17.498z' fill='#FCC400'></path>
    <path d='M29.495 2.905H18.16L6.823 14.24h22.67V2.905z' fill='#575656'></path>
    <path d='M0 35.262h10.014v-3.966H0v3.966z' fill='#F09E00'></path>
    <path d='M5.008 37.294h82.83v-2.032H5.01v2.032z' fill='#575656'></path>
    <path d='M.75 29.858h2.16v-6.995H.75v6.995zM11.015 20.074h3.497v-2.16h-3.497v2.16z' fill='#E2000F'></path>
    <path d='M28.447 35.262h1.05V14.24h-1.05v21.022z' fill='#EE7C00'></path>
    <path d='M53.51 27.23h34.33v4.065H53.51V27.23z' fill='#575656'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyreA'>
    <path d='M64.827 36.593a9.61 9.61 0 0 0 0 13.59c3.753 3.754 9.837 3.754 13.59 0a9.61 9.61 0 0 0-13.59-13.59' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M67.287 39.053a6.13 6.13 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.13 6.13 0 1 0 0-8.67' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M67.287 39.053a6.133 6.133 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.134 6.134 0 0 0 8.67 0l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M68.784 40.55a4.012 4.012 0 0 0 5.676 5.677 4.012 4.012 0 0 0-5.676-5.676' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M65.526 37.293A8.62 8.62 0 1 1 77.72 49.486a8.62 8.62 0 0 1-12.192-12.193m-.385-.386c-3.578 3.578-3.578 9.384 0 12.963 3.58 3.58 9.385 3.58 12.964 0 3.578-3.58 3.578-9.385 0-12.963-3.58-3.58-9.386-3.58-12.964 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyreB'>
    <path d='M13.038 36.593c-3.754 3.754-3.754 9.838 0 13.59a9.61 9.61 0 0 0 13.59 0c3.754-3.752 3.754-9.836 0-13.59a9.61 9.61 0 0 0-13.59 0' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M15.498 39.054a6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.13 6.13 0 0 0 8.67 0 6.13 6.13 0 0 0-8.67-8.67' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M15.498 39.054a6.13 6.13 0 1 0 8.67 8.67l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M16.996 40.55a4.012 4.012 0 1 0 5.675 5.677 4.014 4.014 0 0 0-5.674-5.676' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M13.737 37.293a8.622 8.622 0 0 1 12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0 12.192 8.622 8.622 0 0 1-12.193 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0-12.192m-.385-.385a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0 12.962c3.578 3.58 9.384 3.58 12.962 0a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0-12.962 9.164 9.164 0 0 0-12.962 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
  <g class='tyreC'>
    <path d='M44.406 36.593c-3.753 3.754-3.753 9.838 0 13.59 3.754 3.755 9.838 3.755 13.59 0 3.755-3.752 3.755-9.836 0-13.59-3.752-3.753-9.836-3.753-13.59 0' fill='#1A1A18'></path>
    <path d='M46.868 39.054a6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0 8.67 6.128 6.128 0 0 0 8.67 0 6.128 6.128 0 0 0 0-8.67 6.13 6.13 0 0 0-8.67 0' fill='#9B9B9B'></path>
    <path d='M46.868 39.054a6.13 6.13 0 1 0 8.67 8.67l-8.67-8.67z' fill='#C5C5C6'></path>
    <path d='M48.364 40.55a4.014 4.014 0 1 0 0 0' fill='#868685'></path>
    <path d='M45.106 37.293a8.622 8.622 0 0 1 12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0 12.192 8.622 8.622 0 0 1-12.192 0 8.622 8.622 0 0 1 0-12.192m-.385-.385a9.164 9.164 0 0 0 0 12.962c3.58 3.58 9.385 3.58 12.963 0 3.58-3.578 3.58-9.384 0-12.962a9.164 9.164 0 0 0-12.962 0' fill='#3B3A39'></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In the future, you will be able to do:

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-box: fill-box;
```

But not until `transform-box` is supported properly in all browsers.

Comment: PS. Hopefully I got that explanation mostly right... :)

Comment: Update: Both Chrome and Firefox now behave the same. They also both support `transform-box`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same problem. 
Wheels wheeled around the entire cart and not around its axis. In all browsers the `transform-origin` properties helped.

```
transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
```

But not in Mozilla.
For Mozilla i used static values in pixels.

```
-moz-transform-origin: 136px 110px 0px;
```

[My codepen example](https://codepen.io/Jackkill/pen/VXjzgX?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to save up some time calculating these static positions. Just pass **x**, **y** percent values, a selector and execute right in the browser console:

```
;(function getStaticCoords(x, y, elementId) {
  var coord = $(elementId)[0].getBBox()
  var coordW = coord.width * x / 100
  var coordH = coord.height * y / 100
  return coord.x + coordW + 'px ' + (coord.y + coordH / 2 + 'px')
})(50, 50, '#myDOMElement')
```

Comment: use this without jquery: `(function getStaticCoords(x, y, elementId) {
  var coord = document.querySelector(elementId).getBBox();
  var coordW = coord.width * x / 100;
  var coordH = coord.height * y / 100;
  return coord.x + coordW + 'px ' + (coord.y + coordH / 2 + 'px');
})(50, 50, '#myDOMElement')`