# SVG animateTransform not working same as css3 transform

Tags: css, svg, transform, animatetransform

SVG animateTransform not working same as the css3 transform.

```css
svg.truck {
  overflow: visible;
}
.smoke{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: smoke 1.5s infinite ease-out;
}
@keyframes smoke {
  from {transform: translate(0, 5px) scale(1, 1);}
  to { transform: translate(40px, 10px) scale(4, 4);}
}
```

```html
<svg class='truck' height='53' viewBox='0 0 93 53' width='93' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <g>
    <circle cx='90' cy='35' fill='#000' r='2.5'>
      <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' dur='1.5s' from='1' repeatCount='indefinite' to='4' type='scale'></animateTransform>
      <animateTransform additive='sum' attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' dur='1.5s' from='0, 5' repeatCount='indefinite' to='40,10' type='translate'></animateTransform>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
<hr>
<svg class='truck' height='53' viewBox='0 0 93 53' width='93' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <g class='smoke-group'>
    <circle class='smoke' cx='90' cy='35' fill='#000' r='2.5' />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that SVG animations don't have the ability to set transform-origin like you can with CSS.  So the scale transform is affecting the position as well as the size.

The simplest solution is put the circle at the origin and resposition it with the parent group element.

Also, to match the CSS, you need to switch the order of your `<animateTransform>` elements.

```css
svg.truck {
  overflow: visible;
}
.smoke{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: smoke 1.5s infinite ease-out;
}
@keyframes smoke {
  from {transform: translate(0, 5px) scale(1, 1);}
  to { transform: translate(40px, 10px) scale(4, 4);}
}
```

```html
<svg class='truck' height='53' viewBox='0 0 93 53' width='93' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <g transform="translate(90,35)">
    <circle cx='0' cy='0' fill='#000' r='2.5'>
      <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' dur='1.5s' from='0, 5' repeatCount='indefinite' to='40,10' type='translate'></animateTransform>
      <animateTransform additive='sum' attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' dur='1.5s' from='1' repeatCount='indefinite' to='4' type='scale'></animateTransform>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
<hr>
<svg class='truck' height='53' viewBox='0 0 93 53' width='93' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <g class='smoke-group'>
    <circle class='smoke' cx='90' cy='35' fill='#000' r='2.5' />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Does this kind of solution work for `transform rotate` ?

Comment: It should.  Although rotate is unique in that you can optionally provide the centre of rotation in addition to the angle.  For example `<animateTransform ...type="rotate" from="0,10,10" to="180,10,10">`

Comment: Could you have a look this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153201/transform-origin-not-working-in-firefox-browser-even-properites-in-percentage-va