# Rotate SVG via CSS3 anchor not in the middle

Tags: css, animation, svg

I've designed an SVG in illustrator, and got it rotating with CSS3 but its rotating from top left.

Is there anyway I can set the anchor to the center of the shape?

Thank you!

Comment: Post code - lots of things could be happening to cause this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforms in SVG are around the origin (0,0) and there is no `transform-origin` in SVG [yet](http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.it/2012/03/css-transform-origin-coming-to-svg.html), like there is in CSS.

There are ways to *fake it* but they are not that straightforward: [How to set transform origin in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711610/how-to-set-transform-origin-in-svg)