# D3.js,CSS3 - rotate rectangles to have in a straight line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, css-transforms

I'm using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) to create a arc and 4 rectangels. These Ractangles are dividing Donut into parts.

I want Ractangles to be aligned in straight line

```
var width=200,height=300,innerRadius =100, outerRadius=80;
var wheel = d3.select("#wheel")
 .append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height)

arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0).endAngle(2*Math.PI)

rectData = [
  {x:width/2,y:height/2},
  {x:width/2,y:height/2},
  {x:width/2,y:height/2},
  {x:width/2,y:height/2},
]
rect = wheel.selectAll("g.rect")
  .data(rectData).enter()
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform",function(d,i){
   var rotate = 90*i;
   return "translate(100,150) rotate("+rotate+")"
 }).attr("class","rect")

rect.append("rect")
  .attr("width",20).attr("height",outerRadius)

wheel.append("path").attr("d",arc)
  .attr("transform","translate("+width/2+","+height/2+")")
  .attr("class","donut")
```

I'm using transform-origin, but not working.

[http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/1/)

Comment: What's the result you're looing to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`transform-origin` is a CSS property but you are rotating with an SVG attribute.

SVG `rotate` allows you to set the [origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714140/16363) but for you situation it might just be easier to fix the translate:

```
.attr("transform",function(d,i){
  var rotate = 90*i;
  var rotX = 100, rotY = 150;
  if (i === 0){
    rotX -= 10;
  } else if (i === 1){
    rotY -= 10;
  } else if (i === 2){
    rotX += 10;
  } else if (i === 3){
    rotY += 10;
  }
  return "translate("+rotX+","+rotY+") rotate("+rotate+")";
});
```

Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/11/).

Comment: this solution works for if rotation is 90deg, but it seems not work or hard to adjust if rotation is 60deg or 30deg.
 
[rotation is 60deg] http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/23/

Comment: That's why I was thinking if `transform-origin` is charm for this

Comment: may be more complex if different rotations as there [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmdr72wc/26/)