# clip-path is not working in firefox even after using inline SVG as source

Tags: html, css, svg, mozilla, clip-path

I have created a right pointing content box using css clip-path polygon, It works well inside chrome, For firefox I have added Inline SVG, but still it is not working.

Here is work in progress link

[Link](http://irrationalwip.com/vnext/applications/indoor/kitchen-cabinets-and-shelves/)

Here is the markup and code I used for creating the right pointing content box

HTML :

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
   <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0 0, 0.95 0, 1 0.5, 0.95 1, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
   </defs>
</svg>
<div class="application-content">
   <h3>clip-path is not working in firefox</h3>
   <p>Hi, I have created a right pointing content box using css clip-path polygon, It works well inside chrome, For firefox I have added Inline SVG, but still it is not working.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.application-content{
  width:35%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 95% 0, 100% 50%, 95% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 95% 0, 100% 50%, 95% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  padding:30px;
}
```

I don't know, where it is going wrong.

**Interesting thing here is, The above code is working when used with jsfiddle or codepen.** I am using latest version of wordpress with a custom code theme.

Here is the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/devineninaresh/pen/NbrWqL)

Comment: I had a similar issue. Check this question and answer that I posted:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202373/animation-for-svg-path-within-clip-path-doesnt-work-in-mozilla

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Your codepen is working for me in FF 49.0.2 on Win7.

Comment: @RaHuL-HouseJavascript .. Sorry I could not follow your example.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau....Thats the problem, It is working in codepen, but not in my project. If it works in codepen then it should work in my project as well, but i dont understand why it is not working.