# Why does transform-origin not work for Firefox using inline SVG and is there an alternative?

Tags: css, firefox, svg, inline-svg

I found inconsistencies in Firefox compared to Chrome, Edge, and Opera. Each browser handles `transform-origin` fine when using a CSS class. However, when I place `transform-origin` on an SVG element as an attribute, FF ignores the effect. Demo code below. My main question is how to get around this, but I'm also curious to know if this is expected behavior.

CSS `transform-origin` works in FF.

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'> 
 <style> 
  .centered{   
   transform-origin: center;
  }
 </style>
 <path fill='#500' d='M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z' transform='scale(2)' class='centered'/>
</svg>
```

Inline SVG doesn't seem to recognize `transform-origin` (works consistently in Chrome/edge)

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'> 
 <path fill='#500' d='M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z' transform='scale(2)' transform-origin='center'/>
</svg>
```

---

Edit: Another user pointed out this question is similar to [How to set transform origin in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711610/how-to-set-transform-origin-in-svg), but their premise is super broad (how to) and either wrong or outdated (posted 8.5 years ago).

> "I tried using the transform-origin attribute, but it does not affect
>   anything."

Perhaps browser support has improved, but my question specifically shows `transform-origin` works perfect as a CSS rule in all modern browsers or as a presentational attribute in all modern browsers except FireFox. That differentiation is likely what led to one solution being unique to this thread and a second solution that is a new take on the other threads answers.

Not to mention their question is centered around JavaScript implementation and was published at a time when FireFox didn't recognize keywords like "center" or unitless numbers which detracts from the core SVG markup problem which is that FireFox interprets the presentational attribute `transform-origin=''` different than other browsers.

Comment: It works. Just seems like a hack to translate to center, apply desired effects, then undo translate. Using that solution would be `transform='translate(500 500) scale(2) translate(-500 -500)'` instead of `transform='scale(2)' transform-origin='center'`. If no one else has a better solution, I will use this out of necessity for consistency. Just odd FF recognizes transform-origin only when used as a class.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `transform:scale` here? Are you going to change it dynamically later? If not, you might just update the `d` attribute instead.

Comment: It's a relatively recent [change](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/688) to the SVG specification

Comment: Yes @KoshVery, I am altering shapes dynamically. My demo code is stripped down to the essential concept. My app connects a range input to complex SVG shapes to quickly scale, rotate, move, etc. Transform makes that easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem but I am (as yet) unable to give you a comprehensive reasoning why it works.

The first important thing to know is that you can *chain* **SVG Transforms**.

So, wherever you write `transform="scale(2)"`, you can add a `translate(x, y)` to the chain, like this:

```
transform="scale(2) translate(x, y)"
```

So far, so good... but if `scale` is `2`, then what values should we give to `x` and `y` of `translate`?

To find out, I decided to superimpose larger and subimpose smaller scaled versions of your SVG shape (one for each colour of the rainbow) and see what patterns I could find.

Over the top of your **grey** shape, I positioned an identically sized **green** shape.

I gave the **green** shape a transform of:

```
transform="scale(1) translate(0, 0)"
```

so that it would be exactly congruent with your original **grey** shape.

Then I set about subimposing larger scaled versions (**yellow**, **orange**, **red**) and superimposing smaller scaled versions (**blue**, **indigo**, **violet**).

I predicted that `x` and `y` in each case would relate to the `scale` factor applied to that shape and also to the overall size of the original `viewBox`.

With 3 smaller versions and 3 larger versions, the pattern emerged:

- **Red**, `8` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 8) - 1000)`
- **Orange**, `4` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 4) - 1000)`
- **Yellow**, `2` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 2) - 1000)`
- **Green**, `1` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 1) - 1000)`
- **Blue**, `0.5` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 0.5) - 1000)`
- **Indigo**, `0.25` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 0.25) - 1000)`
- **Violet**, `0.125` times as large / `x` & `y` transform value is `50% of ((1000 / 0.125) - 1000)`

From this, we can conclude, that if you are positioning a shape centered at `50%, 50%` of your `viewBox` and you want to display the shape in that same position with `scale(2)`, you must *also* apply a `translate` for `x` of:

```
50% of ((width of canvas / scale-factor) - (width of canvas))
```

where `50%` corresponds to the `x` position you want to centre the shape over.

And a `translate` for `y` of:

```
50% of ((height of canvas / scale-factor) - (height of canvas))
```

where `50%` corresponds to the `y` position you want to centre the shape over.

This works consistently, but I haven't spent enough time staring at it yet, to properly understand why.

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

<!-- Grey Original -->
<path fill="#555" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" />

<!-- Red Transform [50% of ((1000 / 8) - 1000) is -437.5] -->
<path fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(8) translate(-437.5, -437.5)" />

<!-- Orange Transform [50% of ((1000 / 4) - 1000) is -375] -->
<path fill="rgb(255, 125, 0)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(4) translate(-375, -375)" />

<!-- Yellow Transform [50% of ((1000 / 2) - 1000) is -250] -->
<path fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(2) translate(-250, -250)" />

<!-- Green Transform [50% of ((1000 / 1) - 1000) is 0] -->
<path fill="rgb(0, 125, 0)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(1) translate(0, 0)" />

<!-- Blue Transform [50% of ((1000 / 0.5) - 1000) is 500] -->
<path fill="rgb(0, 0, 125)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(0.5) translate(500, 500)" />

<!-- Indigo Transform [50% of ((1000 / 0.25) - 1000) is 1500] -->
<path fill="rgb(63, 0, 255)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(0.25) translate(1500, 1500)" />

<!-- Violet Transform [50% of ((1000 / 0.125) - 1000) is 3500] -->
<path fill="rgb(199, 125, 243)" d="M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z" transform="scale(0.125) translate(3500, 3500)" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Ah... okay. I've just seen @KoshVery's link comment beneath the question at the top. I can see that (if we take the orange shape as an example), when the `viewBox` is `1000 x 1000`, then `transform="scale(4) translate(-375, -375)"` is actually just another reformulation of `transform="translate(500, 500) scale(4) translate(-500, -500)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, the answer marked correct works in all cases. However, I'm writing another solution because it's the easiest to implement. But please note it only works for `transform` and not for `patternTransform`. While non-FireFox browsers recognize `transform-origin` for both attributes, my solution doesn't work for `patternTransform` on FireFox.

Adding `transform-origin` in a style attribute (`style='transform-origin:center'`) instead of its own presentational attribute (`transform-origin='center'`) works for `transform`, as demonstrated below. This even works for SVGs in data URIs.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>    
    <path fill='#500' d='M500 500 400 400 400 600 600 600 600 400z' transform='scale(2)' style='transform-origin:center'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: See [bug 1581691](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1581691)